# Best way to create a webcomic-like platform

Tags: json, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm creating a webcomic like platform but I'm having problems on how I should do it.

I would like to have the same type system as the average webcomic website like :

- **www.example.com** -> Return the last comic
- **www.example.com/356/** -> Returns the comic number 356

And so on.

Which I don't understand is, I want to provide a json based system in order to help other access the comics and create an app (or even a website) which would load our comics in order.

What would be the best way to do this ?

- Creating a php for uploading new webcomics which would create a new folder with the respective number, an index.html inside and a json file
- Use Apache ReWrite and use a single php file to load every comic making the server things that it is loading a page (like /1/) and then another one for the JSON.
- Another way which I'm not thinking of ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would make a REST service that serves up json, then both your front end website (maybe using AngularJS) and anyone who wants to make an app for you can consume the same data from the REST service. Here's a good REST tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-a-restful-web-service-with-slim/

Comment: That information is quite usefull and I'll keep it :) But it doesn't solve my main question. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a combination of both your points.

One main php template file (index.php) for presentation on the front end (as described in point two) that sources its data from the filesystem (as described in point one) which is folders containing images and the json data for each comic.

What you DONT want is to have multiple front end presentation files that you have to change all of them when you want to change one thing on the front end. So the idea of having multiple index.html files is a no-no.

Combined with my comment above - you can take this advice to make one main back end that serves up the json for your comics based on urls like:

```
http://mycomix.com/comic/123
http://mycomix.com/comics
```

that hands back the data for a single or multiple comics.

Then you (or whoever) can consume that however you like.

Is that closer?